# I'm connecting a PowerPivot query to a MS Analysis server cube. double record

Tags: mdx, cube, powerpivot

I'm connecting a PowerPivot query to a MS Analysis Server Cube. The query result i get contains double records for a single dimension (personnelnr). This because of a name change during a day in the middle of the month.
I want to get a return in which there is only the last known name in that month.
I'm trying to use the LastChild command but this doesn't work.

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Roosteruren] }  ON COLUMNS, 
  NON EMPTY 
   { ([Roosterdatum].[Jaar].[Jaar].ALLMEMBERS * 
      [Roosterdatum].[Jaar maand nr].[Jaar maand nr].ALLMEMBERS *
      [Medewerker excl salaris].[SAP nr].[SAP nr].ALLMEMBERS * 
      [Medewerker excl salaris].[Achternaam].[Achternaam].LastChild *
      [Zend Profitcenter]
FROM [IK]) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

Clearly i must be doing something wrong. But i'm not a novice mdx user.
Can anybody help?

Comment: A name change that results in duplication of dimension members would often be regarded as incorrect data, and developers would ask the database administrators to fix this. Clearly there is only one person/object and the information should be stored in one place. Creating two members that represent the same person/object seems wrong.

Comment: @MagnusSmith duplicate member names is ok in `olap` ... although only if they are members of different hierarchies. So I might have a hierarchy called fiscal year that has a member 1st Jan in it but also there might be a hierarchy calendar year also with a member 1st jan. Similarly I could have a hierarchy in the Employees dimension called Social committee with a member Magnus Smith and then that is repeated in the hierarchy Top Employees.

Comment: where is your ON ROWS ?

Comment: @whytheq - perhaps duplication was the wrong word to use. I was talking about the situation where there are two members yet they both represent the same physical entity (e.g. an employee who changes their name). I've had to deal with cubes like this before, when pubs changed their names, and we were tracking sales.

Answer (score 1):

`GENERATE` seems over the top. I think there must be a much simpler way than this:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    { [Measures].[Roosteruren] }  ON COLUMNS, 
  NON EMPTY 
GENERATE(
    { [Roosterdatum].[Jaar].[Jaar].MEMBERS * 
      [Roosterdatum].[Jaar maand nr].[Jaar maand nr].MEMBERS *
      [Medewerker excl salaris].[SAP nr].[SAP nr].MEMBERS* 
      [Zend Profitcenter]
    } AS Y
  , TAIL( Y.CURRENT * [Medewerker excl salaris].[Achternaam].[Achternaam].MEMBERS, 1)
)
ON ROWS
FROM [IK]
```